# JSP/Java/HTML | How do I create a ActionListener

Tags: java, html, jsp

I just started with JavaEE. I have a `<input type="number">` and a `<button>`. When I click the button I want it to read my `<input>`.

What I have allready tryed:

```
<form action="<jsp:useBean id="year" class="ch.his.logic.Year"/>">
   <input type="number" value="200" name="year" id="inputYear" placeholder="Year">
   <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

I know for this I have to write into my action atribute.

And here comes my Question: how do I link this Form with my Java class and how do I call my Methodes.

This is my Javafile:

```
public class Year implements Serializable {

   public Date date;
   private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy" );

   public void setDate() throws ParseException {
       int year = request.getParameter( 'inputYear' );
       date = format.parse( "01/01/" + year );
   }

   public String getDate() {
       return format.format( date );
   }

}
```

:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to use struts2:

index.jsp:

```
<s:form action="yearAction">
    <s:textfield name="year" type="number" label="year" value="200" />
    <s:submit value="Calculate"/>
</s:form>
```

Year.Java:

```
public class Year implements Serializable {

   public Date date;
   private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy" );

   // add this function
   public String execute(){
        return "success";
   }

   public void setDate() throws ParseException {
       int year = request.getParameter( 'inputYear' );
       date = format.parse( "01/01/" + year );
   }

   public String getDate() {
       return format.format( date );
   }

}
```

And also add the struts2 configuration file to the context root, struts.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <package name="myPackage" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="yearAction" class="ch.his.logic.Year" method="execute">
            <result>/path-to-your-result.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```